# Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

Tags: c#, xna

Heres my whole code, maybe my variables are in correct, i'm not to sure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace PickUpTheCrewGame
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class PickUpTheCrewGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        public enum State
        {
            Menu,
            Playing,
            Gameover,
        }

        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        SpriteFont messageFont;
        SpriteFont playerScoreFont;
        Texture2D backgroundTexture;
        Rectangle backgroundRectangle;
        Texture2D menuImageTexture;
        Rectangle menuImageRectange;
        Texture2D gameoverImageTexture;
        Rectangle gameoverImageRectangle;
        Sprite BlueBall;
        Sprite GreenBall;
        Sprite OrangeBall;
        Sprite PinkBall;
        Sprite RedBall;
        Sprite c;
        Sprite YellowBall;
        public Texture2D menuImage;
        public Texture2D gameoverImage;

        //---player scoresyer
        int playerScore = 0;
        int highScore = 0;

        //Lists
        List<sharks> sharks = new List<sharks>();
        List<Sprite> crew = new List<Sprite>();
        List<int> highscoreList = new List<int>();

        //highScoreList.Add(score);


        //Set First State
        State gameState = State.Menu;

        HUD hud = new HUD();

        public PickUpTheCrewGame()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            //sreen size
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
            menuImage = null;
            gameoverImage = null;


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            //enable the mousepointer
            //IsMouseVisible = true;
            base.Initialize();
        }

        public static bool _highScore (int playerScore)
        {
            if(playerScore >_highScore)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Save(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.TextWriter textOut = null;
            try
            {
                textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);
                Save(textOut);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (textOut != null) textOut.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Save(TextWriter textOut)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
                {
                    textOut.WriteLine(crew1.location.X);
                    textOut.WriteLine(crew1.location.Y);
                }

                foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
                {
                    textOut.WriteLine("Shark");
                    textOut.WriteLine(enemySprite.location.X);
                    textOut.WriteLine(enemySprite.location.Y);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        public void Load(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.TextReader textIn = null;
            //try
            //{
            textIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            Load(textIn);
            //}
            //catch (Exception e)
            //{
            //    throw e;
            //}
            //finally
            //{
            if (textIn != null) textIn.Close();
            //}
        }

        private void Load(TextReader textIn)
        {
            foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
            {
                crew1.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                crew1.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            }
            foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
            {
                enemySprite.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                enemySprite.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            hud.LoadContent(Content);
            //-----LOAD THE MENU BACKGROUND-----
            menuImageTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("menuImage");
            menuImageRectange = new Rectangle(0, 0,
                Window.ClientBounds.Width,
                Window.ClientBounds.Height);

            //------LOAD INGAME BACKGROUND-----
            backgroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");
            backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle(
             0, 0, // top left hand corner
             Window.ClientBounds.Width,
             Window.ClientBounds.Height); // size of screen display

            //GAMEOVER IMAGE BACKGROUND
            gameoverImageTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("gameoverImage");
            gameoverImageRectangle = new Rectangle(
                0, 0,
                Window.ClientBounds.Width,
                Window.ClientBounds.Height);


            //-------Captains crew-------

            c = new Sprite(new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0),
                  Content.Load<Texture2D>("WhiteBall"), Color.White);

            BlueBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(640, 450),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueBall"));
            crew.Add(BlueBall);

            GreenBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(250, 600),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("GreenBall"));
            crew.Add(GreenBall);

            OrangeBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(115, 400),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("OrangeBall"));
            crew.Add(OrangeBall);

            RedBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(500, 600),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("RedBall"));
            crew.Add(RedBall);

            YellowBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(800, 400),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("YellowBall"));
            crew.Add(YellowBall);

            PinkBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(25, 175),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("PinkBall"));
            crew.Add(PinkBall);

            //--------Sharks------
            sharks s = new sharks(new Vector2(1000, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);
            s = new sharks(new Vector2(900, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);
            s = new sharks(new Vector2(800, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);

            messageFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("messageFont");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //----------This gets the time value---------
            float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            //--------------keyboard input---------------
            //Exit
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                this.Exit();
            //Save
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                Save("test.txt");
            //Load
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.L))
                Load("test.txt");

            //Directional Movement
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                c.velocity.X = -350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                c.velocity.X = 350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                c.velocity.Y = 350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                c.velocity.Y = -350;


            //UPDATING PLAYING STATE
            switch (gameState)
            {
                case State.Playing:
                    c.Update(elapsed);
                    foreach (Sprite cr in crew)
                    {
                        cr.Update(elapsed);
                    }
                    c.col = Color.White;

                    //----sharks intersects with whiteball----
                    foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                    {
                        if (c.bounds.Intersects(s.bounds))
                        {
                            gameState = State.Gameover;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                    {
                        s.Update(elapsed, c.location);
                    }



                    //hud.Update(gameTime);
                    //----sprites intersect with whiteball----
                    foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
                    {
                        if (c.bounds.Intersects(crew1.bounds))
                        {
                            //gameState = State.Gameover;
                            playerScore += 1;
                            crew1.bounds.X = 10000;
                            crew1.bounds.Y = 10000;
                            crew1.location.Y = 10000;
                            crew1.location.X = 10000;
                            break;
                        }
                    } break;


                //UPDATING MENU STATE
                case State.Menu:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            gameState = State.Playing;
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                //UPDATING GAMEOVER STATE
                case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Back))
                        {
                            if (playerScore > highScore)
                            {
                                highScore = playerScore;
                                SavehighScore();
                            }
                            playerScore = 0;
                            sharks.Clear();
                            crew.Clear();
                            gameState = State.Menu;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            switch (gameState)
            {
                //DRAWING PLAYING STATE
                case State.Playing:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, backgroundRectangle,
             Color.White);
                        c.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        //FOR EACH CREW DRAW
                        foreach (Sprite cr in crew)
                        {
                            cr.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        }
                        //FOREACH SHARK DRAW
                        foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                        {
                            s.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        }

                        hud.Draw(spriteBatch);

                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, playerScore.ToString(),
                new Vector2(200, 0),
                Color.White);

                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, " Player Scores - ",
                            new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                        break;


                    }
                //DRAWING MENU STATE
                case State.Menu:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(menuImageTexture, menuImageRectange, Color.White);
                        break;
                    }
                //DRAWING GAMEOVER STATE
                case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(gameoverImageTexture, gameoverImageRectangle, Color.White);
                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, "Your Final Score was - "  + playerScore.ToString(),new Vector2 (0,0), Color.White);
                        break;
                    }
            }


            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the fist error:

> Error  1   Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

I'm doing highscores in XNA and have gotten an error message:

```
public static bool _highScore (int playerScore)
        {
            if(playerScore >_highScore)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I also get an error messeage at the end saying:

> 'The name 'SavehighScore' does not exist in current context'

Code:

```
case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Back))
                        {
                            if (playerScore > highScore)
                            {
                                highScore = playerScore;
                                SavehighScore();
                            }
                            playerScore = 0;
                            sharks.Clear();
                            crew.Clear();
                            gameState = State.Menu;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
```

That is my whole gameover state of which when the player dies, its meant to show there highscores.

IF you could advise a way of whats best way to save a highscore in a method, that would be really helpful as well please:

I am rather new to XNA, still learning. If anyone could be any help would really appreciate it. Thank You

Comment: If you really want help, post a small yet complete reproduce of your problem. Don't copy your entire code-base to SO. That doesn't help.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the post in sections

Comment: This is *far* from a *minimal* working example. Btw. this probably won't work: `public static bool _highScore (int playerScore) { if(playerScore >_highScore) ...` and this is probably the place where the exception is thrown. (Take a look at the stack trace of the exception)

Comment: @Corak It's not an exception, it's a compile time error.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - ah yes, you're right of course. Even better to find the exact position. ^_^

Comment: @shaneo - The *variable* containing the highscore is called `highScore`, but you are comparing `playerScore` to `_highScore` (note the underscore) which is the name of a *method*. That's what the first error means. The second error tells you, that you're trying to call a method called `SavehighScore` which does not exist; meaning you need to implement it before you can call it.

Comment: In the if statement when I did (player>highscore), i get an error saying 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PickUpTheCrewGame.PickUpTheCrewGame.highScore'

Comment: when I use this.(playerScore>this.highScore). I got an error message, 'Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer'

Comment: Generally if one is going to post compile-time errors in their code, please just post the line where the error occurs and relevant code.   These sort of problems are arguably best solved by going through the Errors window of Visual Studio, following the clear suggestions on how to fix it.  A good book on _Learning C# 101_ is also recommended.  This will help us help you.  I wish you well!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool _highScore (int playerScore)
    {
        if(playerScore >_highScore)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

> "Here the fist error: Error 1 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'"

The reason why you get this error is because you are comparing playerScore (an int) to the _highScore method (which is also called incorrectly).

What are you trying to accomplish here? If you just want a convenience method to check the high score:

Refactor to:

```
public bool IsHighScore() 
{
        return playerScore > highScore;
}
```

Then, in your gamestate:

```
case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Back))
                        {
                            if (IsHighScore())
                            {
                                highScore = playerScore;
                                SavehighScore();
                            }
                            playerScore = 0;
```

And as others have said, you have to write your SavehighScore method.

Answer (score 0):

just use if(playerScore > this.highScore)